# Converting labels to points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, point, annotation, maplex

is there a way to convert labels, created by Maplex labeling engine to point features?

In MapInfo and CAD software, it's possible to convert labels to points. Those point features include a text and a rotation for this point. When text is horizontal, it includes all the text. When the text is curved, it included one char for each point with the rotation in degrees. That makes it possible to use the labels in other software or store them in a database.

ArcGIS 10 only allows to convert labels to annotations, which result in polygons.

Comment: Would a tool that converts polygons to label points and retains the polygon attributes (not the annotations to label points) be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely difficult to accomplish. and even harder to describe.
I'll take one feature type and hopefully you can get around that way.

Polygon.
1. using ettools create cetnroids from polygons.
2. import shape file into autocad map3d with object data from attributes.
3. close drawing and open a new one.
4. attach point drawing and query with alter properties.
5. select text and set the text value expression to the field you desire.
If you desire more than one you will have to repeat the process but they will be stacked on top of each other.
6. continue by running the query as a draw query with all label points as the type Whether location all or specific layer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have access to AutoCAD Map :-(

Comment: unless you have advanced level license I think you need another tool to help accomplish. ET tools can help or CAD would be two ways to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know any function in ET Tool, which could help on this problem :-(

Comment: Oh, actually I'm on "Advanced". It's an educational license at University (ArcInfo) :)